# WCF Duplex channels and high memory usage

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a Client that connects to a self hosted service (ServiceA) which in turn connects to another self hosted service (ServiceB) using a WCF duplex channel all the way through, essentially Service A is a bridge that does very little apart from pass on the calls. The memory usage is very high on Service A and it crashes with an OutOfMemoryException at around 1000 connections. Which doesn't seem that high to me.

Service B does not appears to have the same issue which makes me think the issue is in the creation of duplex channel on the client side Client configuration is as below. I have written a simple app mimicking me setup and uses no security at all and the issue isn't present.

Endpoint:

```
<endpoint address="net.tcp://10.1.1.10:61002/SessionService/1/Federated" 
    behaviorConfiguration="ClientBehavior" 
    binding="CustomBinding" 
    bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding1" 
    contract="Company.Services.Common.Interfaces.ISessionService" 
    name="SessionService">
    <identity>
        <dns value="ServerName.Company.com" />
    </identity>
</endpoint>
```

Binding:

```
<binding name="CustomBinding1" openTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="infinite">
    <transactionFlow />
    <reliableSession maxPendingChannels="20" inactivityTimeout="00:01:00" />
    <security authenticationMode="SecureConversation">
    <secureConversationBootstrap  authenticationMode="IssuedTokenForSslNegotiated" messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncryptAndEncryptSignature">
        <issuedTokenParameters>
            <issuer address="https://IdentityServer.dev.local:443/IdentityServer/issue/wstrust/mixed/certificate" 
            binding="ws2007HttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ws" />
            <issuerMetadata address="https://IdentityServer.dev.local:443/IdentityServer/issue/wstrust/mex" />
            <additionalRequestParameters>
                <wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
                    <EndpointReference xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
                        <Address>http://Company.com/</Address>
                    </EndpointReference>
                </wsp:AppliesTo>
            </additionalRequestParameters>
        </issuedTokenParameters>
    </secureConversationBootstrap>
    </security>
    <binaryMessageEncoding>
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binaryMessageEncoding>
    <tcpTransport maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="5242880" 
        connectionBufferSize="8192" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" 
        channelInitializationTimeout="00:01:00" maxBufferSize="5242880" 
        maxPendingConnections="20" maxOutputDelay="00:00:00.2000000" maxPendingAccepts="5" 
        transferMode="Buffered" listenBacklog="25" portSharingEnabled="true" teredoEnabled="false">
        <connectionPoolSettings groupName="default" leaseTimeout="00:00:00" idleTimeout="00:00:00" 
        maxOutboundConnectionsPerEndpoint="0" />
    </tcpTransport>
</binding>
```

Behaviour:

```
<behavior name="ClientBehavior">
    <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate findValue="CN=ServerName.Company.com" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" />
        <serviceCertificate>
            <authentication certificateValidationMode="ChainTrust" revocationMode="NoCheck" />
        </serviceCertificate>
        </clientCredentials>
</behavior>
```

Has anyone seen anything like this? From a memory trace there appears to be a lot (potentially too much) of Session Security Token caching occurring. I am using a cached ChannelFactory to create each of the channels. I'm currently in the process of removing the secure conversation.

Thanks.

Comment: Update:

I have found that a majority of the memory is being used by the SessionSecurityTokenCache on each of the duplex channels. Overriding the base implementation on the SecurityTokenHandlers for each ChannelFactory appears to resolve the issue but my custom implementation is never being reached although everything seems to be functioning correctly. Does anyone know why this would be the case? I'm some what lost now!